# Android: app reinstall fails

Tags: android, installation

I have uninstalled my app (debug version) with the options on my phone. But if I reinstall it with another version (signed) I get an error message that it already exists. But I do not see a symbol in the phone. I have to use adb uninstall. This happens on different devices.

Is this normal behavior or is there something wrong with my app?

Comment: "But I do not see a symbol in the phone" - what do you mean by symbol? Icon? You should uninstall it from settings (or use `adb uninstall`)

Comment: What failure code you receive?

Comment: Icon correct. I can uninstall with adb, but I want to know why it does not completely uninstall if i drag it to the recycle bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is that i was using 2 packages

Answer (score 0):

If the signatures do not match, the old app must be uninstalled before another app with the same package name can be installed. The old application can be uninstalled from command line (adb uninstall) or just using the normal Android UI (go the all applications view, long tap the application icon there and drag it into trashbox that should appear at the top).

It is really very strange and wrong if you do not have your application icon at all. Even if you do not supply one, the default icon (a green Android) should be used together with your application name. But maybe you are talking about the main desktop where the icon may not be installed by default. You need to go to application list instead. For 4.1.0, the application list is opened with the button having six white dots in two rows, all surrounded by the circle, at the bottom centre.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to install a signed app with the same package name as the unsigned version, it will return an error saying that it cannot be done. What you have to do is to check that the app really is uninstalled on your device before installing the new, signed version.

Comment: yes but why is it not completely unistalled when draging the app icon to the recycle bin?

Comment: The app will never get uninstalled if you only remove the shortcut. You'll have to remove the app manually by going into Settings > Apps and then scroll through the list until you find the app and uninstall it.

Comment: im a developer. i know the difference between draging a shortcut from startscreen to recycle bin and draging an application from the apps menu to the recycle bin.